# Multiple linked datatables

Tags: datatables

This is related to the thread http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/211/i-want-create-two-linked-datatables/p1, but a variant of it.

I have 2 datatables in the same page. 
Datatable 1 - I have made one of the columns, a link which will call another javascript function with a parameter (the value of the column).
The javascript function makes creates datatable #2 in the same page using sAjaxSource using the parameter passed in.

Example to relate: 
Datatable #1: List of all the companies
Datatable #2: List of all employees for each company. The CompanyId is the clickable field in datatable #1, and on click it loads the datatable #2 with only the employees of that company..

Issue: 
The issue that i am facing is, when i click on a link in datatable #1, it loads datatable #2 fine. But, it does not refresh the data which i click on other links.

Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you -

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/891/multiple-tables-and-ajax-source-table-identification/p1